# Add columns between specific columns in .dat file python

Tags: python, bash, file

I have large number of files with different line numbers and same column numbers in a directory.I want to loop through all the files and add new columns with value(1.00) between specific columns(between 4 and 5, 12 and 13).I want to edit and add columns of data to same files.

My data looks like

```
2.0 3.0 2.0 2.0 ...
1.0 0.0 2.0 1.0 ...
.
.
.
```

Thanks.

Comment: Share what you have tried and where you are getting issues

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
import os

dir_path = './' # path to the required directory

def add_float(val, index, dat_file):
    lines = []
    with open(dat_file, 'r') as rd_file:
        for line in rd_file:
            line = line.strip().split()
            line.insert(index, str(val))
            lines.append(' '.join(line))

    with open(dat_file, 'w') as wrt_file:
        wrt_file.write('\n'.join(lines))

for file in filter(os.path.isfile, os.listdir(dir_path)):
    add_float(1.00, 3, file) # here, 1.00 is the value to be inserted after the 3rd column
```

Comment: Thanks, it works actually for a file. But, if I want to apply this operation to all files in a directory, what I have to do?

Comment: use `os.listdir()` to list all the files in the required directory, loop through the list and call `add_float()` function.